# Aache Spark java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, apache-spark

Here is my files:

```
package org.apache.spark.rdd;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class DataPreperation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("DataPreperation");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(config);

        JavaRDD<String> custRDD = sc.textFile("Data/customer.csv");
        JavaRDD<String> transRDD = sc.textFile("Data/transection.csv");


        ////Identify distinct rows in Customer.csv
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> CustKP = custRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(String x) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new Tuple2(x.split(",")[0],x);
            }
        });
        //System.out.println(CustKP.count()+"All rows 25");

        //System.out.println(CustKP.keys().distinct()+"distinct rows 25");


        JavaPairRDD<String, String> CustKPReduced = CustKP.reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String, String>() {

            public String call(String x, String y) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub``
                return y;
            }
        });

        //System.out.println(CustKPReduced.count()+"distinct rows 21");
        //System.out.println(CustKPReduced.collect());



        JavaPairRDD<String, String> transKP = transRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(String x) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new Tuple2(x.split(",")[1], x);
            }
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, String> transKpDist = transKP.reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String, String>() {
            public String call(String x, String y) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return y;
            }
        });



        JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, String>> CustTransKP= CustKPReduced.join(transKpDist);


        //System.out.println(CustTransKP.count());

    //  System.out.println(CustKPReduced.take(10))

//      System.out.println("Customer Distinct Rows by Key :"+CustKPReduced.count());
//      System.out.println("Total Joined table Rows : "+CustTransKP.count());
//      System.out.println("Distinct Joined Table Rows :"+CustTransKP.distinct().count());
//      System.out.println("Transaction total rows + Distinct Rows:"+transKP.count()+" +" +transKP.distinct().count());

//      JavaRDD<String> subKeys = CustKPReduced.subtractByKey(CustTransKP).keys();
//      System.out.println(subKeys.distinct().count());
//      JavaRDD<String> TotalCustKeys = CustTransKP.distinct().keys();//22797
//      JavaRDD<String> TotalKeys = subKeys.union(TotalCustKeys);
//      System.out.println(TotalKeys.count());
//      TotalKeys.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Data/Total_Keys");
//      
        //System.out.println(CustTransKP.take(1));
        //JavaRDD<String> transKeys = transKP.distinct().keys();
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> transId=CustTransKP.values();

        JavaRDD<String> transKey = transId.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, String>() {
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> x) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return x._1().split(",")[3];//Here if I change [3] to [2] or [1] it is not showing me exception.
            }
        });
        CustTransKP.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Data/CustTransKP");
        transId.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Data/transId");
        transKey.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Data/trans_Key");
        //JavaRDD<String> transKey = 
        //System.out.println("Count of tanrsKey:"+transKey.count());
        //System.out.println("First 10: "+transKey.take(10));



    }

}
```

Here is Output :

```
16/01/06 09:05:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/06 09:05:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/01/06 09:05:05 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 8.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 8
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 8 (main at <unknown>:0) failed in 8.285 s
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: main at <unknown>:0, took 8.317993 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1124)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation.main(DataPreperation.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DataPreperation$5.call(DataPreperation.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.100.35:4040
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/06 09:05:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-b90705cb-50d2-40fc-9518-e0aed907f570
```

transId is Rdd of valueof PairRdd-CustTransKP which consists of two files customer.csv and Transaction.csv.

Whenever I try to access elements of Transaction.csv by return x._1().split(",")[3]; it throws exception but not when turn x._1().split(",")[2];

Comment: What is the string you're splitting on. It seems pretty obvious that there isn't a 4th element.

Answer (score 2):

Look like maybe your split dosent work as you expect ,try using split(",", -1) so empty elements beetwen separator will be keeped in your final rdd and all array will have the same number of elements.

split(",",-1) basically means keep empty values at the end. By default it is split(regex, 0) which discards empty values